# How to convert a string list into an integer in python

Tags: python, string, list, int

In my python Script I have:

```
user = nuke.getInput("Frames Turned On")
userLst = [user]
print userLst
```

Result:

```
['12,33,223']
```

I was wondering How I would remove the `'` in the list, or somehow convert it into int?

Comment: You want to turn three numbers separated by commas into an int? How should that work?

Comment: @Ignacio: To explain what Nick probably means: If you "remove the `'`" in the list `['12,33,223']`, you get `[12,33,223]` -- at least this is how I read it...

Answer (score 20):

Use `split()` to split at the commas, use `int()` to convert to integer:

```
user_lst = map(int, user.split(","))
```

Answer (score 9):

There's no `'` to remove in the list.  When you print a list, since it has no direct string representation, Python shows you its `repr`—a string that shows its structure.  You have a list with one item, the string `12,33,223`; that's what `[user]` does.

You probably want to [split](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) the string by commas, like so:

```
user_list = user_input.split(',')
```

If you want those to be `int`s, you can use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
user_list = [int(number) for number in user_input.split(',')]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[int(s) for s in user.split(",")]
```

I have no idea why you've defined the separate `userLst` variable, which is a one-element list.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> ast.literal_eval('12,33,223')
(12, 33, 223)
```

Comment: Not so good if the user is allowed to enter a single number.

Comment: Sure, but that's easy enough to catch.

Comment: why not just `eval('12,33,223', {})` ? That will only allow the same things as `literal_eval` do. BTW OP may not want things other than numbers

Comment: And things that are not numbers are easy enough to catch.

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> result = ['12,33,223']
>>> int(result[0].replace(",", ""))
1233233
>>> [int(i) for i in result[0].split(',')]
[12, 33, 233]
```

Answer (score -2):

You could use the join method and convert that to an integer:

```
int(''.join(userLst))
```

> 1233223

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, or address the actual problem.

Comment: @Eevee - How does this not convert a string list into an int?

Comment: It's a single string in a list, not a list of strings.