# Converting list of one string to list of integers

Tags: python

I have a list that looks like this:

```
mylist = ['1,2,3']
```

It is a list of one string. I want to convert this to a list of integers like:

```
mylist = [1,2,3]
```

I tried `[int(x) for x in mylist.split(',')]` but it doesn't work.
Can someone please help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6378889/how-to-convert-a-string-list-into-an-integer-in-python

Comment: Hint ! str is itself a list and hence mylist is list of list (speaking on a broader term) . So you need to dissect two list's not one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't work is that your list only contains one item - `"1,2,3"`. Split the first (and only) item in the list on comma, then [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) `int` to the items you get:

```
mylist = ['1,2,3']
print map(int, mylist[0].split(","))
```

Prints

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

If you have more than one item in your list, you can do

```
print map(int, [sub for item in mylist for sub in item.split(",")])
```

Answer (score 3):

Using list comprehension. [**`split`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) is a string method

```
[int(j)  for i in  mylist for j in i.split(',')]
```